# Python denies that discord.ext exists although I have downloaded it

Tags: discord, bots

I've downloaded discord.py from the command shell, but when I try to write the code, python denies discord.ext's existence.
I don't want to show my token here, but I did type a token in my original code

```
import os

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = ''

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} succesfully logged in!')

bot.run(TOKEN)

async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return





    if message.content == 'yee yee':
        await message.channel.send (f'yee {message.author}')



    await bot.process_commands(message)



bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

`import` imports a *module* name, or imports names from the specified *module*.  If the only file you have is `discord.py` then whatever `discord.ext` names is not an available module.  Possibly you need to download additional modules, or possibly `discord.ext` is simply something (a class, for example), from which one cannot `import`.